# Player prize system

Tags: c#

I have coded a prize system in where I add a prize in the database and it calls the CheckPrizes(player) every time a player logs in to the application. I won't go in to detail of how they log in but thats the basics of it.

PrizeManager.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using Sahara.Base.Game.Players;

namespace Sahara.Base.Game.Prizes
{
    internal sealed class PrizeManager
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Prize> _prizes;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<int>>  _prizeLogs;

        public PrizeManager()
        {
            _prizes = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Prize>();
            _prizeLogs = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<int>>();

            LoadPrizes(false);
        }

        private void LoadPrizes(bool clearBefore)
        {
            if (clearBefore && _prizes.Count > 0)
            {
                _prizes.Clear();
            }

            using (var mysqlConnection = Sahara.GetServer().GetMySql().GetConnection())
            {
                mysqlConnection.OpenConnection();
                mysqlConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `server_rewards` WHERE `enabled` = @enabled");
                mysqlConnection.AddParameter("enabled", "1");

                var dataTable = mysqlConnection.GetTable();

                if (dataTable == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (DataRow prizeRow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    _prizes.TryAdd(Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["id"]), new Prize(Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["id"]), Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["reward_start"]), Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["reward_end"]), Sahara.GetServer().GetUtility().GetPrizeTypeFromString(Convert.ToString(prizeRow["reward_type"])), Convert.ToString(prizeRow["reward_data"]), Convert.ToString(prizeRow["message"])));
                }

                mysqlConnection.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        public void CheckPrizes(Player player)
        {
            if (player?.GetPlayerData() == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var prizeEntry in _prizes.Where(prizeEntry => !ReceivedPrize(player.GetPlayerData().PlayerId, prizeEntry.Key)).Where(prizeEntry => prizeEntry.Value.Ready()))
            {
                prizeEntry.Value.OnReceive(player);
            }
        }

        public void LogReceivedPrize(int playerId, int prizeId)
        {
            if (!_prizeLogs.ContainsKey(playerId))
            {
                _prizeLogs.TryAdd(playerId, new List<int>());
            }

            if (!_prizeLogs[playerId].Contains(prizeId))
            {
                _prizeLogs[playerId].Add(prizeId);
            }

            using (var mysqlConnection = Sahara.GetServer().GetMySql().GetConnection())
            {
                mysqlConnection.OpenConnection();

                mysqlConnection.SetQuery("INSERT INTO `server_reward_logs` VALUES (@playerId, @prizeId)");
                mysqlConnection.AddParameter("playerId", playerId);
                mysqlConnection.AddParameter("prizeId", prizeId);
                mysqlConnection.RunQuery();

                mysqlConnection.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        private bool ReceivedPrize(int playerId, int prizeId) => _prizeLogs.ContainsKey(playerId) && _prizeLogs[playerId].Contains(prizeId);
    }
}
```

Prize.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sahara.Base.Game.Players;
using Sahara.Core.Net.Messages.Outgoing.Packets.Inventory.Purse;

namespace Sahara.Base.Game.Prizes
{
    internal sealed class Prize : IPrize
    {
        private readonly int _prizeId;
        private readonly int _prizeStart;
        private readonly int _prizeEnd;
        private readonly PrizeType _prizeType;
        private readonly string _prizeData;
        private readonly string _prizeMessage;

        public Prize(int prizeId, int prizeStart, int prizeEnd, PrizeType prizeType, string prizeData, string prizeMessage)
        {
            _prizeId = prizeId;
            _prizeStart = prizeStart;
            _prizeEnd = prizeEnd;
            _prizeType = prizeType;
            _prizeData = prizeData;
            _prizeMessage = prizeMessage;
        }

        public bool Ready()
        {
            var now = Sahara.GetServer().GetUtility().GetUnixNow();
            return (now >= _prizeStart && now <= _prizeEnd);
        }

        public void OnReceive(Player player)
        {
            switch (_prizeType)
            {
                case PrizeType.None:
                    return;
                case PrizeType.Badge:
                    if (!player.GetPlayerData().GetBadgeManagement().HasBadge(_prizeData))
                    {
                        player.GetPlayerData().GetBadgeManagement().GiveBadge(_prizeData, true);
                    }
                    break;
                case PrizeType.Credits:
                    player.GetPlayerData().Credits += Convert.ToInt32(_prizeData);
                    player.SendMessage(new CreditBalanceMessageComposer(player.GetPlayerData().Credits));
                    break;
                case PrizeType.Duckets:
                    player.GetPlayerData().Duckets += Convert.ToInt32(_prizeData);
                    player.SendMessage(new HabboActivityPointNotificationMessageComposer(player.GetPlayerData().Duckets, Convert.ToInt32(_prizeData)));
                    break;
                case PrizeType.Diamonds:
                    player.GetPlayerData().Diamonds += Convert.ToInt32(_prizeData);
                    player.SendMessage(new HabboActivityPointNotificationMessageComposer(player.GetPlayerData().Diamonds, Convert.ToInt32(_prizeData)));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PrizeType.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sahara.Base.Game.Prizes
{
    internal enum PrizeType
    {
        Credits,
        Badge,
        Duckets,
        Diamonds, 
        None,
    }   
}
```

GetUnixNow method:

```
public double GetUnixNow()
{
    var ts = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    return ts.TotalSeconds;
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### PrizeManager.cs

First, [don't call it Manager](https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/).

You don't need a parameterized query here, everything is hardcoded, `WHERE 'enabled' = '1'` is enough:

```
mysqlConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `server_rewards` WHERE `enabled` = @enabled");
mysqlConnection.AddParameter("enabled", "1");
```

Then this:

```
_prizes.TryAdd(Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["id"]), new Prize(Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["id"]), Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["reward_start"]), Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["reward_end"]), Sahara.GetServer().GetUtility().GetPrizeTypeFromString(Convert.ToString(prizeRow["reward_type"])), Convert.ToString(prizeRow["reward_data"]), Convert.ToString(prizeRow["message"])));
```

This line is too long, create a Prize object first (with every parameter in its own line) and then add it to the collection:

```
var prize = new Prize(Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["id"]),
                      Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["reward_start"]), 
                      Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["reward_end"]), 
                      Sahara.GetServer().GetUtility().GetPrizeTypeFromString(Convert.ToString(prizeRow["reward_type"])), 
                      Convert.ToString(prizeRow["reward_data"]), 
                      Convert.ToString(prizeRow["message"])));
_prizes.TryAdd(Convert.ToInt32(prizeRow["id"]), prize);
```

After that, remove the line `mysqlConnection.CloseConnection();`, the connection is already in the `using` block, it will be disposed.

This query is mind bending, refactor it or explain it in a comment:

```
foreach (var prizeEntry in _prizes.Where(prizeEntry => !ReceivedPrize(player.GetPlayerData().PlayerId, prizeEntry.Key)).Where(prizeEntry => prizeEntry.Value.Ready()))
```

#### Prize.cs

Use DateTime and DateTimeOffset structures instead of integers for handling time (`_prizeStart, _prizeEnd, Ready()`), and don't use the `GetUnixNow` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't

```
SELECT *
```

Explicitly get only the columns you need

Use a `DataReader` rather than a `DataTable`

If you use `HashSet` for _prizeLogs you don't have to check Contain.  You can just Add and if it is there then nothing happens